# Rviz PluginlibFactory load wrong path

Tags: ros, rviz, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to run google cartographer demo and get this follwoing error

`[ERROR] [1613722041.399069111, 1588377398.223712458]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'Submaps' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /opt/ros/noetic/lib//libcartographer_rviz.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /opt/ros/noetic/lib//libcartographer_rviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4absl16strings_internal9CatPiecesB5cxx11ESt16initializer_listINS_11string_viewEE)`

Seem like  the PluginlibFactory loads

`/opt/ros/noetic/lib//libcartographer_rviz.so`

instead of

`/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libcartographer_rviz.so`

This is should be trivial but I don't know where to apply the solution.  [This](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer_ros/tree/master/cartographer_rviz) is the submap source code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372231/rviz-pluginlibfactory-load-wrong-path/) by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2021-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-19**:
The duplicated forward slash (ie: `/`) is not the problem.

The problem is the missing symbol: `absl::strings_internal::CatPieces[abi:cxx11](std::initializer_list<absl::string_view>))`.

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2021-02-19**:
Thank you, I've just realized that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just forget to compile the rviz plugin and its dependency (abseil-cpp) using same C++ standard. After compiling all of it using C++17 this problem is no longer exist.

---

Originally posted by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) with karma: 96 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0